# Cannot write text in placeholder in react

Tags: react

I'm new to react and learn it through a tutorial about ethereum. Here is how the form with multiple fields is created:

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (

<input placeholder={placeholder}

type={type}

step="0.0001"

value={value}

onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}

className="noTailwind"

/>

);

<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />

<Input placeholder="Amount (ETH)" name="amount" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />

<Input placeholder="Keyword (Gif)" name="keyword" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />

<Input placeholder="Enter message" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
```

Then handleChange is called in TransactionContext.jsx:

```
const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });

const handleChange = (e, name) => {

setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));

};
```

When I type in the form I see the first letter (keypress) appears in the console, but nothing is shown in the form and other key presses are not registered.

Please help me out with solving this error

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're encountering an issue where the input values are not updating correctly in your React form. This could be due to various reasons. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check the Initial State**: Ensure that the initial state in your `TransactionContext.jsx` is properly set. In your code, you've initialized `formData` with empty strings, which is correct.
2. **Check the Input Component**: Verify that the `<Input />` component is being rendered correctly in your parent component and that the `handleChange` function is being passed correctly.
3. **Console Logging**: Since you mentioned that you see the first letter appearing in the console but not in the form, it suggests that the `handleChange` function might not be updating the state correctly. Double-check the function, and consider adding more `console.log` statements to debug the behavior. Ensure that `name` is being passed correctly and that `formData` is being updated as expected.
4. **Key Events**: Make sure there are no conflicting event handlers or other code that might interfere with the key events. Check for any JavaScript errors in the console.

If you still can't resolve the issue after checking these steps, please provide more details or code snippets related to your `handleChange` function and how the `formData` state is used in your form so that I can offer more specific assistance.